# Polymorphic engines, in managed languages?

Tags: c#

I have developed my programming skills to a point where i can do most everyday stuff quite well and easily, and I thought one day, that making a polymorphic engine would really test my skills, and I was wondering if anybody had any pointers on making a polymorphic engine for a program, where to start, maybe some code examples? really anything would be helpful at this point :)

here are some of my resorces:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphic_code <- this is the one im particularly interested in..
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphic_engine

Comment: My guess is polymorphic engine has something to do with run-on sentence? :)

Comment: Are you planning to code managed viruses? :)

Comment: @Yury, Why not? I wouldn't know to much on the subject, so why would you want to write unmanaged vs managed?

Comment: @mazzzzz: Well, I don't want to write viruses neither in managed nor in unmanaged code :). AFAIK there were a number of viruses written in C# but I have no idea were those viruses polymorphic ones or not. :)

Comment: @Yury: A polymorphic engine is simply a way to conceal the payload of the application, i mostly want it for source protection. people can decompile the decryptor, and work towards unencrypting the actual source, but if they launch the application again the encrypted application and decryptor will both be different code.. its not fool proof but I'd think it would prevent quite a challenge to stealing code

Comment: @Yury: Especially in a managed language like C#, where decompiling is easy.

Comment: @Tommy very true, just look at reflector!
Also changing the decryptor, not just the payload would be the most magical piece of code ever crafted (if you do it, send it to me!).

Comment: @Tommy, did my answer help? Anything that needs clarification?

Comment: @simon: it would, if i understood how to "transform the byte array, during the emitting process, to a format which the decryptor can read and emit to real il bytes. The emitting process will create all necessary tokens, so it should work." :P

Comment: @Tommy, transform the byte[] into real readable (for those selective few) IL-code (ldstr, ldc.i4.0, etc), then back again. Or any other format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I mention in a comment, this is possible in .NET using the magical [System.Reflection.Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.aspx) namespace. You just create a new DynamicMethod and emit any [valid] opcodes into it, and then call Invoke.

I've spent the last few hours trying to build a simple showcase for a "clean" program that would create new copies of itself with encrypted il code. The approach I went for was having an Exec method, grab the il-bytes (using [MethodBase.GetMethodBody](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getmethodbody.aspx)), encrypt them and emit a new assembly having the iv+key and the encrypted bytes. The main method would then decrypt, create a new DynamicMethod, call [DynamicILInfo.SetCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.dynamicilinfo.setcode.aspx) and hopefully work. It didnt.

The encryption/decryption thingie worked, and my emitted code was correct. However, it seems that you can not take the raw bytes from one assembly and just execute them in another.

Data (from BitConverter.ToString) from run A and run B.
A: 28-01-00-00-0A...
B: 28-11-00-00-0A...

Unless you know the byte values for every opcode, open ILDAsm, choose View > Show bytes. There's also a View > Show token values which also helps debugging. Press ctrl-m for View > MetaData > Show! to resolve tokens and other magical creatures.

"28 01 00 00 0A" -> CALL 0A000001 -> [According to ctrl-m] MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod

These different token values are generated sequentially by the compiler. This means that it's impossible to guarantee that everything will work using raw bytes. Just think of the common case where the compiler only created tokens for every method call require to decrypt your byte array, and you call Console.WriteLine in your encrypted code. No such token is written, and you'll end up with a "BadImageFormatException: Bad binary signature" when invoking your dynamic method.

I leave it as a task for the read (or until I'm bored again) to transform the byte array, during the emitting process, to a format which the decryptor can read and *emit* to real il bytes. The emitting process will create all necessary tokens, so it should work.

If you want to chicken out from all the awesomeness of emitting opcodes, do some dynamic compilation from code stored as strings (which can of course be encrypted). This, however, lose in both cleverness, coolness and everything else that can be used to measure the pure awesomeness of the developer (YOU!). Check out [this tutorial](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/dynamicCode/DynamicCode.htm) for a quick display of dynamic compilation and execution of C# within strings.

Comment: Did you ever end up getting bored again? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as I know a polymorphic engine is just the code you want run encrypted, then pair that with a decryption module.  So all you need to do is encrypt your code into a string.  Then you write a decypter.  I would use a basic symmetric encryption class like hxxp://www.obviex.com/samples/Code.aspx?Source=EncryptionCS&Title=Symmetric%20Key%20Encryption&Lang=C%23
After that, run the code in memory, something like hxxp://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655

EDIT:
If you wanted to get more indepth, you could always write your own encryption/decryption, make it something like base_64 (no key), instead of AES (with a key)

Hope that helps,
Max

Comment: Polymorphism is code that is not only encrypted/decrypted, but is CHANGED every time. Every time it is ran, the code should be different, while still keeping the original algorithm in tact.

Comment: Oh, that is interesting.  I guess you could write your own basic language, each of its commands would then be able to be translated into multiple C# commands.  This would allow you to create your code, then parse it?  
An example might be the different loops you could use any of them to loop through an array, and you could change the variable names on top of it.  
That would be pretty polymorphic to me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphic code is not possible in C# or managed languages.  It requires you to produce assembly code for a specific platform (.NET is not platform-specific) into a buffer or data area, then jump into that buffer or data area.  There are many layers of software and hardware in place to stop that happening - see the NX bit on Wikipedia for example.

You can't do it in managed code.  You'd have to write it in unmanaged code and call into that.

Hope that helps.

---

Please see the helpful comment on this answer, as you can dynamically create managed code from managed code; I was considering unmanaged code, as is used on the whole.

Comment: But couldnt you emit IL-code into a DynamicMethod and Invoke() that?

Comment: Yes, suggest you write an answer about that!

Comment: @simon you really should, that sounds like a very good solution.