# Convert class method into IL and execute it at runtime

Tags: c#, reflection, cil, methodinfo

I want to convert a method into an IL codes from a class and then execute it by invoke it. The example I am following is from msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.methodbuilder.createmethodbody(v=vs.110).aspx.

It shows exactly what I need, my problem is to generate the ILcodes from a class method.

So basically I need to fill the following

```
byte[] ILcodes = new byte[] {
  0x02,   /* 02h is the opcode for ldarg.0 */
  0x03,   /* 03h is the opcode for ldarg.1 */
  0x58,   /* 58h is the opcode for add     */
  0x2A    /* 2Ah is the opcode for ret     */
};
```

from a method defined in a class for example:

```
public class MethodBodyDemo
{ 
    public int Add(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

I tried the following call to fill the byte array:

```
var ILcodes = typeof(MethodBodyDemo).GetMethod("Add").GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray();
```

The following is the example I am creating but it gives an exception:
"Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program."

```
public class MethodBodyDemo
{ 
    public int Add(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }
    // This class will demonstrate how to create a method body using 
    // the MethodBuilder.CreateMethodBody(byte[], int) method.
    public static Type BuildDynType()
    {
        Type addType = null;
        AppDomain currentDom = Thread.GetDomain();
        AssemblyName myAsmName = new AssemblyName();
        myAsmName.Name = "MyDynamicAssembly";
        AssemblyBuilder myAsmBldr = currentDom.DefineDynamicAssembly(
                           myAsmName,
                           AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
        // The dynamic assembly space has been created. Next, create a module
        // within it. The type Point will be reflected into this module.
        ModuleBuilder myModuleBldr = myAsmBldr.DefineDynamicModule("MyModule");
        TypeBuilder myTypeBldr = myModuleBldr.DefineType("Adder");
        MethodBuilder myMthdBldr = myTypeBldr.DefineMethod("Add",
                                MethodAttributes.Public |
                                MethodAttributes.Static,
                                typeof(int),
                                new Type[]
                                {typeof(int), typeof(int)});
        // Build the array of Bytes holding the MSIL instructions.
        // byte[] ILcodes = new byte[] {
        //  0x02,   /* 02h is the opcode for ldarg.0 */
        //  0x03,   /* 03h is the opcode for ldarg.1 */
        //  0x58,   /* 58h is the opcode for add     */
        //  0x2A    /* 2Ah is the opcode for ret     */
        // };
        var ILcodes = typeof(MethodBodyDemo).GetMethod("Add").GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray();
        myMthdBldr.CreateMethodBody(ILcodes, ILcodes.Length);
        addType = myTypeBldr.CreateType();
        return addType;
    }
    public static void TestExecMethod()
    {
        Type myType = BuildDynType();
        Console.WriteLine("---");
        Console.Write("Enter the first integer to add: ");
        int aVal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter the second integer to add: ");
        int bVal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        object adderInst = Activator.CreateInstance(myType, new object[0]);
        Console.WriteLine("The value of adding {0} to {1} is: {2}.", aVal, bVal, myType.InvokeMember("Add", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, adderInst, new object[] { aVal, bVal }));
    }
}
```

Execute by calling:

```
MethodBodyDemo.TestExecMethod();
```

Any help please?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are you trying to do in the end? :) Anything wrong with calling the method directly (or indirectly using reflection), or creating instructions using `System.Reflection.Emit.ILGenerator`?

Comment: I'm a little confused - are you basically trying to dynamically add a new method to an object and then invoke it?

Comment: What i am looking for is copying a method send it to another system and that system execute it, but the other system does not know about the library being used. The code above do so, the only thing is how to fill the ILcode?

Comment: Interesting approach, some sort of validator/anti-piracy or just bored? If it is nothing secret, you can execute C# code from text or dynamically load assembly/use MEF on library.

Comment: Your end-goal is not possible as-is; the byte code contains metadata tokens generated at compile time. The last time I checked (2010) they were incrementing numbers based on the order the compiler found them. Calling String.Join may resolve to token 0A000001 in your code, but may be 0A000009 at your target computer. Or it may not even exist as a metadata token if your target computer doesn't call that method in their assemblies. You would need to transform the byte array into a format that the recipient can compile/resolve itself. Somewhat relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3193423

Comment: It will work within the same exact framework version and platform provided that the method is defined in one of the core, ngen'd assemblies.  I noticed that I was getting the same method table pointers on different machines as long as I stayed in the same framework and obviously bitness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build your project in `Release` mode, and do one of the following:

Remove the `MethodAttributes.Static` attribute here

```
MethodBuilder myMthdBldr = myTypeBldr.DefineMethod("Add",
                           MethodAttributes.Public |
                           MethodAttributes.Static,
                           typeof(int),
                           new Type[]
                           {typeof(int), typeof(int)});
```

Or change this method to be `static`

```
public int Add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

And this should work for you.

[image]

**But**, I saw in comments that you want it to pass bytes to other system and run it, my answer is just for the example you have in the question. In reality this is not going to work because the reason that Simon Svensson wrote in comment. (Unless all methods are statics and do pure operations (like return 3+4) without any reference to other methods\types\fields.)

You still can (theoretically) do some magic to make it work but it's not practically.

Answer (score 4):

I am the author of a library that does a similar thing. It reads the opcodes of an existing method, reinterprets them back to generic opcode items that contain i.e. MethodInfo instead of the numbered token and builds a method copy out of these. This works cross-assembly and would work in your case too.

It was designed to monkey patch games but could be modified to transfer the generic opcodes in "clear text" to a different system so that the destination could do a type lookup and thus obtain the correct opcode for the local assembly.

The project is MIT licensed and is called [Harmony](https://github.com/pardeike/Harmony).